# Page margin, header and footer configuration

Tags: header-footer, margins, letters

This is how my letter looks like

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{letter}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\newcommand{\DocumentTitle}{Motivation Letter}
\newcommand{\Author}{John Smith}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\hdrfont[ LetterSpace=5.0, WordSpace=1.0, Scale=0.9, Color=FFFFFF ]{Arial}

\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1.8in]{geometry}
\linespread{1.2}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footers
\setlength{\headheight}{0.5in}
\fancyhead[L]{\hdrfont\textbf{\DocumentTitle} \\ \emph{\Author}}
\fancyhead[R]{\hdrfont\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{\hdrfont\textbf{\DocumentTitle} \\ \emph{\Author}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\hdrfont\thepage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
\name{ \Author }
\signature{ \Author }
\begin{letter}{}
\renewcommand{\today}{ February 16, 2009 }


\opening{To Whom It May Concern,}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\closing{Respectfully,}
My Letter
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

What like the pdf looks like

```
--------------------------------------- PAGE BEGIN
                                        H
--------------------------------------- HEADER RULE
                                        M1
To Whom It May Concern,---------------- TEXT BEGIN
My Letter
Respectfully,-------------------------- closing
                                        S
John Smith----------------------------- signature
--------------------------------------- TEXT END
                                        M2
--------------------------------------- FOOTER RULE
                                        F
--------------------------------------- PAGE END
```

I want that `H = F` `M1 = M2` and length `S` is too big. But now, `H != F` and `M1 != M2`.
How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For having `H = F` include `includehead,includefoot`  in the option of `geometry`.

For reducing the space between the closing and the signature you can use the `etoolbox` package to patch the distance:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\closing}{6}{2}{}{}
```

or

```
\pathcmd{\closing}{6\medskipamount}{<insert the distance you prefer>}{}{}
```

It seems to me that to vertically center the content of the letter (i.e., `M1 =  M2`) would require a substantial rewriting of the `letter` class. One has to consider whether it does not fit in one page, and then processing it accordingly.

Comment: I added `includehead`,`includefoot` (`\usepackage[hmargin=1in,vmargin=1.2in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}`). Still `H != F`.

Comment: Have you removed the `\setlength{\headheight}` line from your code?